# chrome frame, install it or not?

Tags: html, google-chrome, installation, frame

I'm googling for a while and I didnt find a clear answer to this. If I use Chrome Frame on one of my websites, the visitor, has to install Chrome Frame or not?

Best regards,
Tiago Castro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Get started with Google Chrome Frame**

Enabling Google Chrome Frame is simple. For most web pages, all you have to do is add a single tag to your pages and detect whether your users have installed Google Chrome Frame.

> If Google Chrome Frame is not installed, you can direct your users to
>   an installation page. If Google Chrome Frame is installed, it detects
>   the tag you added and works automatically.

so yes they will need it only if they want it :)

Answer (score -1):

The user will be offered Chrome, but they are not required to install or use it.

Answer (score -1):

No, They need not to install Chrome Frame.

But, if visitors doesn't have google chrome installed it ask to install the chrome browser.